# How retrieve dimensions of predefined packages of USPS using easypost API?

Tags: php, usps, easypost

I am going to use easypost API for USPS shipping, and to use its pre-defined packages for example "SmallFlatRateBox" but I need to know its dimensions to count the package boxes of order items. But I can't find any method to get dimensions of pre-defined packages by their key names. Please guide me how can I get dimensions of pre-defined package?

Here is link of easypost API that I am going to use.
https://www.easypost.com/docs/api

Thank you.

Comment: I can't speak for Easypost but the Shippo docs (same API, but cheaper prices & faster calls) list of package templates incl. dimensions, see https://goshippo.com/docs/#parceltemplates. The list is fairly static so you can save the values locally without making an API call each time.

Comment: I also got response from Easypost, and they are not providing dimensions via API. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

EasyPost does not currently provide a way to programmatically retrieve dimensions for predefined packages; however, this is something we are considering. For now, you can look up dimensions of predefined packages via the carrier specific guides.

TLDR: We have a [USPS Guide](https://www.easypost.com/usps-guide) that details all of the predefined package dimensions.